# Unity 17.04 Desktop Launcher problem for MySQL Workbench

Tags: unity, launcher, mysql-workbench, 17.04

I have just installed the final 17.04 Release.  Having problems with the Unity Launcher (not Dash, don't use that), *compared to what has always worked* in 16.04 & 14.04.

[To create a shortcut on Launcher I always run the program first from the shell, then when it's running I right-click its icon in Launcher and **Lock to Launcher**: if that is not the right way to do things let me know.]

Having locked `mysql_workbench`, when I click icon to launch it does its "flashing" for a few seconds but nothing happens, the application window does not appear?

Possibly relevant: I see that in 16.04 this had created `~/.local/share/applications/mysql-workbench-bin.desktop`.  In 17.04 it has created `~/.local/share/applications/_usr_lib_mysql-workbench_mysql-workbench-bin.desktop`, which looks a bit ugly?

Answer (score 1):

Following a suggestion in another post, I found the Unity Dash.  There I get 3 matching icons for `mysql_workbench`.  All I know is I clicked one, and am now able to **Lock** either from there or from running `mysql_workbench` from a terminal and it works OK again.

I'm sure the multiple icons are symptomatic of something unhelpful.

I have deleted all `~/.local/share/applications/*mysql-workbench-bin.desktop` files.  I no longer get multiple matches from Dash, and the one I do get works fine again.  So I guess that was connected to the problem.